# Typescript: Why different data type on function params don't throw error?

Tags: typescript, type-conversion

```
function add(a:number, b:number):number {
    return a+b;
}
let mynumber:any = "50";
let result:number = add(mynumber, 5);

console.log(result);
```

Why the console print "505" and don't throw an error on "add" function?

If a had typed mynumber as :number I would get an error on declaration line, but in that way shouldn't I get an error too?

Comment: How do you run it?

Comment: Many thanks to all, guys

Answer (score 3):

This is called [type assertion](https://basarat.gitbooks.io/typescript/content/docs/types/type-assertion.html). You are saying to the compiler to treat `mynumber` as [any](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/basic-types.html#any) and that type is a special inbuilt type that is compatible with any type.

In runtime, your `add`-function is doing string conversion and concatenation since you actually are sending in a string instead of a number, so it's basically pure luck that this type-mismatch did not result in a runtime error.

Answer (score 2):

You need to **think about types as sets, categories or groups**. For example, if you declare a number:

```
let a: number;
```

The variable `a` accepts all the values available in the numbers group. The numbers group has an infinite number of possible values.

There are other infinite categories or groups(types) like the `string` type. But there are also categories with a finite number of possible values, for example the `boolean` category.

You can also declare a variable as the union of a few categories:

```
let a: number | boolean;
```

The line above defines a new group that can take an infinite number of possible values including: true, false and all the numbers.

Once you think about types as sets, categories or groups, it is easy to understand why you don't get an error:

```
 let mynumber: any = "50";
```

The `mynumber` is a valid `number` because **the type `any` is the union of all the other types**. This means that `any` is a valid `number`, `boolean`, `string`, etc.

Answer (score 1):

That's because `mynumber` is of type `any`.
When you use `any` it will bypass the type checker and will be alright with everything.

If you change it to `string` you get an error:

```
let mynumber:string = "50";
let result:number = add(mynumber, 5); // error: Argument of type 'string' is not assignable to parameter of type 'number'
```

And more examples of using `any` with no errors:

```
let a = "string" as any;
let b = /a+/g as any;

let c: number = a + b;
```